# MVC simple select count from db and display explained

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with an MVC for the first time and developing a library app for personal dev. I am using the php login [found here](https://github.com/panique/php-login). I am new to php and sql so apologies for any amateur coding, I have taught myself php.

I have been reading for the past two weeks and trying to get my head around how to do the simplest of tasks. Maybe it's the MVC I am working with or it's just my inability to figure it out. I find myself copying chunks of code from one model/view/controller to the next in order to achieve my desired results, however this isn't ideal as I would like to know what the code does or I won't be learning.

I have been doing a lot of independent reading and following tutorials online however most of them are aimed towards CodeIgniter or CakePhp, therefore the syntax is different. I know that once I finally get my head around the syntax and logics then I won't have any issues.

I will use a simple example for reference below. Hopefully somebody will be able to shed some light on this for me and help me out.

I have been trying all day today to select the number of rows in my table and display this on a user profile page as *"You have this number of favourites: x"*.

As I understand, I create the query in my model which is `favouriteTotal()`. I then reference this is the controller and render the view? Using PDO to connect to db.

**login.php (model)**

```
class LoginModel
{
    public function favouriteTotal()
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favourite");
        $query->execute();
        $count = $query->rowCount()       
    }
}
```

**login.php (controller)**

```
class Login extends Controller
{
    function showProfile()
    {
        $login_model = $this->loadModel('Login');
        $login_model->favouriteTotal();
        $this->view->render('login/showprofile');
    }
}
```

**showprofile.php (view)**

```
<div>
    Your have this number of favourites: <? NUMBER OF FAVS HERE ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The `render` method just `require`s the view, meaning anything in the method scope should be available. You should be able to just do `$numberOfFavourites = $login_model->favouriteTotal();` then `echo $numberOfFavourites;` in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a general answer about how it often works... Please tell us what framework you are using if you want a specific answer.

Many MVC applications use a `ViewBag`, a 'Container' of sorts, that gets passed along to the view that's being rendered.

**(Updated the code below to reflect how the used framework passes data to the view)**

*login.php (controller)*

```
class Login extends Controller
{
    function showProfile()
    {
        $login_model = $this->loadModel('Login');
        $this->view->count = $login_model->favouriteTotal();
        $this->view->render('login/showprofile');
    }
}
```

*showprofile.php (view)*

```
<div>
    Your have this number of favourites: <?php echo $this->count; ?>
</div>
```

So, in the controller you assign the value of `$login_model->favouriteTotal()` to `$this->view->count`. Then you render the view. In that view, you call `$this->count` to access the previously sent data.

Comment: It doesn't accept a second parameter for variables, see this file on GH: https://github.com/panique/php-login/blob/master/application/libs/View.php - the second argument is to enable header and footer rendering.

Comment: Updated the answer based on how data is passed to the view on that GH project.

Comment: Yes, this method should be the same when passing data from controllers to views. Watch out for some variations in the data being passed though, like passing arrays (and looping them in the view). Questions about if its a good starting point are very opinionated, my view is it doesn't really matter if you choose framework A or B, as long as you get the basic understanding of the architecture right.

Comment: The query is correct. The php method used to get $count is not. The query returns 1 row, within that row a value of '3'. rowcount returns the number of rows, which would be 1. So, either count the rows of a normal select query `SELECT * FROM favourite` (inefficient) or select the actual value returning from the excisting query. We get way offtopic for this question though! :)

Comment: @Adimeus it would also not show currently as you don't `echo` the result... i.e. `<?php echo $this->count; ?>` not `<? $this->count; ?>`

Comment: Just to note also @Adimeus I had to put the opening `<?php` tag in or else only `count; ?>` printed on screen. Still working on the query getting it to work, however I have accepted your answer thank you.